# rocketMQ run runserver.sh bring sh: /usr/local/rocketMQ/incubator-rocketmq/bin/runserver.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: rocketmq

rocketMQ run runserver.sh bring sh: /usr/local/rocketMQ/incubator-rocketmq/bin/runserver.sh: No such file or directory

what's wrong?

i opend the file 'runserver.sh' and run 'set ff'
it result to fileformat=unix

Comment: Please make your question clearer, how do you unpack , and what's inside, what command did you do ant what's the output or logs.

Comment: ：) I am a fresh man in learning linux, I made a simple mistake in configuring the environment variable.

Comment: If you have solved the problem then you can share your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot configure rocket home.

1.temporary configure rocket home
for example, temporary configure the rocketmq home:  export ROCKETMQ_HOME=/root/rocketmq-all-4.5.1-bin-release
and then start nameserver: sh bin/mqnamesrv

2.forever configure rocket home
in mac os:
open bash_profile: vim ~/.bash_profile
add rocket home,for example: ROCKETMQ_HOME=/root/rocketmq-all-4.5.1-bin-release
source ./.bash_profile